# how do i print the foreign key in a model in django using queryset

Tags: django-models, django-queryset

**Models.py**

```
class tag_table(models.Model):
    tag_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    book_tag = models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.book_tag

class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    book_author = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    book_tag = models.ForeignKey(tag_table ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.book_author,self.book_tag)
```

I am using query in interactive shell(django)

> > > Book.objects.all()[0].book_tag

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1
 in **get**
    rel_obj = qs.get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\query.py", line 385, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
DoesNotExist: tag_table matching query does not exist.*

**How can i access the foreign key "book_tag" by using the object list of model "Book"**

Answer (score 1):

your database schema is incorrect because you are using MVC in Django so you don't need to relate tables in database manually because its outdated and its a little hard too.

here is your hypothetical models i hope it can help

```
class Book(models.Model):
      author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
      tags = models.ForeignKey(Book_Tags)
      def __unicode__(self):  ###__str__() in python3
          return self.author.name
```

1. Author and Book_Tags are two other models that you should define before
2. no need for id. Django will automatically declares it

you can use [Django web Site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/) while writing your codes. its very helpful

for example for writing your models get help from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/)